# City weather in an array of structs

Tags: c++, arrays, string, search

I've been working on a project for school for a number of hours now and I can't figure out why this won't work. It's supposed to gather cities and temperatures from a given text file and load it into an array of structs. Also to be build in is the ability to sort and search through the cities and output the information to the screen.

The file we're given is a list of cities with high and low temperatures. It looks like this:

```
Katmandu, -34, 28
Perth, 92, 105
Chicago, 22, 45
```

The problem I'm having is regarding the search function of the program. 
This is what I have so far:

```
void ShowCities(int count)
{
   const int string_size = 255;
   char searchstring[string_size];
   char lowercase[string_size];
   int numbermatch = 0;

   cout << "Specify the city search string: ";
   _flushall();
   cin.getline(searchstring, string_size);

   qsort(cities, count, sizeof(HiLoTemp), compareAscending);
   _strlwr_s(searchstring);

   for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
   {
      strcpy_s(lowercase, string_size, cities[i].city.c_str());
      _strlwr(lowercase);
      if (strstr(lowercase, searchstring) != 0)
      {
         PrintCityRecord(i);
         numbermatch++;
      }
   }
   cout << numbermatch << "record(s) found." << endl;
}
```

The goal is to be able to search the list of cities for a letter and have the most relevant city names(in order of where the letter appears in the name) output to the screen.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Now you're only finding cities which contains given substring in their names but they are printed in alphabetical order (I assume `cities` array is sorted alphabetically by cities names by qsort function). You should sort them not alphabetically but in order of where the given substring (in your case letter) appears in the city's name before printing.

Comment: @RSahu [Link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13DtNYYlx7lHdCpXMkJkZG3MBIVXiuZp4rq0iAQ87MBE/edit?usp=sharing) to the entire code.

Comment: @michal.z The problem I'm encountering is that it doesn't seem to be comparing the string you enter to the values in the cities array at all. When I run it, it just returns that zero were found. Also, I linked the entire code in the above comment.

Comment: Have you checked whether `searchstring` is correctly assigned a given value?

Comment: Way too much non-standard non-C++ unsafe noise in that code. If this is for a C++ class you should either re-write it to be more idiomatic or get a refund.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Since Marcus mentions it is a school project, I suspect this bad style is enforced by the teacher. I hope Marcus can clarify whether he has the freedom to switch to more idiomatic coding style.

Comment: If the teacher is enforcing the use of things like `_strlwr_s` they need to be punched in the throat.